# How do I show unique constraints of a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I created them, but I forgot which ones they are.

I just want to

1. show them.
2. remove all the constraints on a table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select distinct CONSTRAINT_NAME
from information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'mysql'
```

Answer (score 85):

```
select distinct CONSTRAINT_NAME
from information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where table_name = 'table_name' and constraint_type = 'UNIQUE';
```

Answer (score 26):

This doesn't produce elegant output but is easy to remember:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;
```

Answer (score 7):

This query returns primay keys, unique keys and foreign ones :

```
show indexes from table_name;
```

Answer (score 4):

The OP asked for a single table, which this will do.

In addition, removing the last `where` clause will show all columns for a database which are protected by unique constraints:

```
SELECT
  CONSTRAINT_NAME,
  TABLE_NAME,
  COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'UNIQ%'
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name'
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name';
```

Unfortunately mysql doesn't facilitate the removal of indexes based on a query result. You could execute the output of the following query to drop all unique columns in 2 queries:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  'ALTER TABLE ',
  TABLE_NAME,
  ' DROP INDEX ',
  CONSTRAINT_NAME,
  '; -- drops ',
  COLUMN_NAME,
  ' constraint'
)
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'UNIQ%'
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name';
```

Comment: How to execute this query after concatenation ?