# Find out if column is unique in PHP or Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to check if a column in a database is unique.

How do I do this in PHP/Laravel?

The Schema Builder doesn't provide anything. I also looked into the `DB::` facade. I also tried a general search for "php column is unique"

My purpose is to take a table, add a `'site_id'` column, and then make all the unique columns, say `unique(email)`, become `unique([email, site_id])`

Comment: The underlying database is mysql - if that's important

Comment: `SHOW INDEXES FROM tablename WHERE Column_name='columname' AND NOT Non_unique`

Comment: it seems that people have already answered this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836502/how-do-i-show-unique-constraints-of-a-table-in-mysql

Comment: @Salar - I was hoping for a PHP API - if none exists, and there seems to be done, I'll hit MySQL directly

Comment: Are you trying to make current data unique, or make a table where those columns are unique? if you are just trying to get the unique values can't you just use groupBy in eloquent?

Comment: @ChrisTownsend - Neither, I'm trying to find which columns have a unique constraint

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 8 solution to get table indexes

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

```
$indexes = DB::connection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableIndexes('tablename');

foreach($indexes as $index_name =>$index_data){
    if(!$index_data->isPrimary() && $index_data->isUnique()){
        //Your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @icecub comment - There was no 'PHP' way of getting the data, I needed to use MySQL directly

`$indexList = DB::select(DB::raw("SHOW INDEXES FROM $tableName WHERE NOT Non_unique and Key_Name <> 'PRIMARY'"));`