# Cannot Drop unique constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, information-schema

Using MySql

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME='table_A' 
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA='schema_A' 
    AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE='UNIQUE'
```

when I execute the above query , It runs without any error and returns the name of the unique constraint but when I use it as a subquery , it doesn't work:

```
Alter table table_A
drop index (SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME='table_A' 
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA='schema_A' 
    AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE='UNIQUE')
```

I don't understand what is wrong with the above code.

I tried using a variable also

```
SET @id = SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME='table_A' 
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='schema_A' 
        AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE='UNIQUE'
```

and then

```
Alter Table table_A
Drop index @id
```

It still doesn't work.

EDIT : this gives me the concatenated query

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  'ALTER TABLE TABLE_A DROP INDEX ',
  CONSTRAINT_NAME,
  ';'
)
FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE
TABLE_NAME='TABLE_A' 
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='SCHEMA_A' 
AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE='UNIQUE';
```

Comment: I don't think that a subquery can follow `DROP INDEX`.  You will either have to use dynamic SQL for this, or just get the constraint name and inline it in your `ALTER` statement.

Comment: Can you please explain it with the help of  a code snippet

Comment: Please tell us which _database_ you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2).  "SQL" isn't an actual product, it's just a language which runs on many different products.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48323964/2469308

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya It says "Unknown column 'TABLE_A in 'field list'

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya How to run this concatenated query ?

Comment: @first query will concat and give you a query string as a result. In your code, you get that query string result and then execute that separately